# After join the topic contains duplicate messages

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

Trying to join two streams by a timestamp field in the payload of the messages results in duplicate messages in the output topic. This not expected. How can I avoid this duplication?

I'm using a DSL topology that uses the two streams from two topics. As I'm doing some mapping per stream, this results in two additional topics. Finally after the join the fifth topic is filled with the results and this one shows the duplicated messages. I checked that the other four topics don't contain duplicates. I also noticed that the function that I provide to the kafka streams join function, is invoked repeatedly. This function already shows that duplication occurs.

```
KStream<String, MappedOriginalSensorData> flattenedOriginalData = originalData
                .flatMap(flattenOriginalData())
                .through("mapped-original-sensor-data", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), new MappedOriginalSensorDataSerde()));

        KStream<String, MappedErrorScoreData> enrichedErrorData = errorScoreData
                .map(enrichWithModelAndAlgorithmAndReduceKey())
                .through("mapped-error-score-data-repartition", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), new MappedErrorScoreDataSerde()));


        return enrichedErrorData
                //#3. Join
                .join(flattenedOriginalData, join(),
                        JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMillis(1).toMillis()), Joined.with(Serdes.String(), new MappedErrorScoreDataSerde(), new MappedOriginalSensorDataSerde()))
                //#4. set key
                .selectKey((k,v) -> v.getOriginalKey())
                //#5. Map removing the originalKey field)
                .mapValues(removeOriginalKeyField())
                .through("joined-data-repartition");
```

I expected that the joined-data-repartition topic shows just unique messages based on the payload:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1556626280000,
  "errorSignal": 84.98,
  "originalSignal": 36
}
Key:
1234:a:v2:nord::TE7
Timestamp:
Apr 30th, 2019 14:11:20.00
Offset:
3629
Partition:
0
```

and

```
{
  "timestamp": 1556626280000,
  "errorSignal": 84.98,
  "originalSignal": 36
}
Key:
1234:a:v2:nord::TE7
Timestamp:
Apr 30th, 2019 14:11:20.00
Offset:
3628
Partition:
0
```

see the offset

Comment: Have you enabled exactly-once processing for your application? If not, it may happen that you see duplicates.

Comment: I did try that using spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.processing.guarantee=exactly_once but this causes the app to fail due to Timeoutexception after 60000ms and than it shuts itself down:  All stream threads have died. The instance will be in error state and should be closed. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that some left over state stores on my local disk caused the duplicate messages. That is, I repeated my tests multiple times with wiping kafka storage, but was not aware about the state stores on local disk. Every time I repeated the test (with the same messages) the messages where joined with the content in the state stores which caused duplicate messages.